# Save bulk data using angularjs in c#

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

HTML page code `

```
<div class="panel-heading">Question Answers Form</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="questionanswersForm" name="questionanswersForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="questionpaper" class="col-sm-3 control-label">QuestionPaper</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" name="questionpaper" id="questionpaper" ng-model="question.questionpaperid" required>
                    <option value="">---Please select---</option>
                    <option ng-selected="{{questionpaper.questionpaperid==question.questionpaperid}}" ng-repeat="questionpaper in questionpapers" value="{{questionpaper.questionpaperid}}">
                        {{questionpaper.questionpapername}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="question" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Question</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" id="question" name="question" class="form-control"
                       ng-model="question.questions" ng-required="true" placeholder="question" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="question" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Answers</label>
            <table class="col-sm-6">

                    <tr ng-repeat="row in vm.rows">
                        <td>
                            <input type="radio"  class="form-control" name="group" ng-model="row.iscorrect"  />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="row.answertext" ng-readonly="row.reado" ng-disabled="row.reado" on-focus="!row.readonly" ng-blur="vm.addNewRow(false,'')" />
                        <!--</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="row.value" ng-readonly="row.readonly" ng-disabled="row.readonly" ng-blur="vm.addNewRow('','')" />-->
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button ng-click="vm.editRow($index)">{{row.readonly ? "Edit" : "Save" }}</button>
                            <button ng-click="vm.removeRow($index)">Remove</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

            </table>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3 ">
                    <button id="cancelSave" name="cancelSave" class="btn btn-warning"
                            ng-click="cancel()">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></i> Cancel
                    </button>
                    <button id="submitButton" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary"
                            ng-click="saveQuestionAnswers()">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Save
                    </button>
                    <button id="deleteButton" name="submitForm" class="btn btn-danger"
                            data-ng-show="isEdit"
                            ng-click="modalDelete('md',question)">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

`

Js controller code is

```
contactApp.controller('questionAnsersAddController',
['$scope', 'questionpaperDataService', 'questionDataService', '$window',
function categoryController($scope, questionpaperDataService, questionDataService, $window) {



    var vm = this;
    vm.rows = [{ "iscorrect": false, "answertext": "", "reado": false }];

    vm.addNewRow = function (value,name ) {

        if (vm.rows.length <0) {

            vm.rows.push({ "iscorrect": false, "answertext": "", "reado": false })
            vm.rows[vm.rows.length - 2].readonly = true;
        }
        else {
           // alert('you are creating more than 4 answers!');

            vm.rows.push({ "iscorrect": false, "answertext": "", "reado": false })
            vm.rows[vm.rows.length - 2].reado = true;
        }
    }      

    vm.removeRow = function (index) {
        vm.rows.splice(index, 1);
    }

    vm.editRow = function (index) {
        vm.rows[index].reado = !vm.rows[index].reado;
    }

    $scope.question = {};
    $scope.dt = [];
    $scope.isEdit = false;  



    $scope.questionpapers = [];

    loadQuestionPaperData();

    function loadQuestionPaperData() {
        questionpaperDataService.getQuestionPapers()
        .then(function () {
            $scope.questionpapers = questionpaperDataService.questionpapers;
        },
            function () {
                //Error goes here...
            })
            .then(function () {
                $scope.isBusy = false;
            });
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $window.location = "#/question";
    };

    $scope.saveQuestionAnswers = function () {         
        if ($scope.questionanswersForm.$invalid) return;
        $scope.dt[0] = vm.rows[0];

        alert(angular.isArray($scope.dt));
      //  $scope.dt = JSON.stringify(vm.rows);
            //vm.rows;
            //

        questionDataService.addQuestionAnswers($scope.question, {dt: vm.rows })
        .then(function () {
            $window.location = "#/question";
        },
        function () {
            //Error        
        })
    };
}]);
```

JS Data service is

```
contactApp.factory('questionDataService', ['$http', '$q',
function ($http, $q) {



    var _addQuestionAnswers = function (_questionansers, dt) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var controllerQuery = "question/InsertQuestionAnswers";

        $http.post(controllerQuery, _questionansers, dt)
          .then(function (result) {
              //Success
              deferred.resolve();
          },
          function (error) {
              // Error
              deferred.reject();
          });
        return deferred.promise;
    };




    return {

        addQuestionAnswers: _addQuestionAnswers

    }
}]);
```

CS controller code is

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("InsertQuestionAnswers")]
    public async Task InsertQuestionAnswers(question _question, List<answer> dt)
    {
        try
        {
            await ClientFactory.HelloWorldClient.InsertQuestionAnswersAsync(_question,dt);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

When i click on Save button on page, data shows in js controller and also show in js data service but 
In CS controller, list dt show null.

Kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code below

```
$http.post(controllerQuery, _questionansers, dt)
      .then(function (result) {
          //Success
          deferred.resolve();
      },
      function (error) {
          // Error
          deferred.reject();
      });
    return deferred.promise;
```

From angularjs [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post), post accept 3 parameters:

> post(url, data, [config]);

So I think **_questionansers** and **dt** must be passed as one object.

Hope it's help

Comment: Thanks for solution